# How do I dowload editable PDF within <iframe> when submit in java jsp

Tags: java, jsp, iframe

I have a interactive PDF file in iframe,  i would like to save this PDF after the submitting form with the insterting data of the user , i used some methode JS but i cannt do it, i work with java jsp portlet project using Liferay

```
<form:form class="form-horizontal" id="Form" action="${SendPdfFormURL}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">

//Adding src with the PDF file
    <iframe id="iframe" name="iframe" type="application/pdf" src="Test.pdf/" style="width: 1024px; height: 1024px;" frameborder="0"></iframe>       
        <button type="submit"> Save Demande </button>

</form:form>
```

Comment: The `<iframe>` is not a field of the `<form>`, it is ignored on submit.

Comment: So what's the solution to display a interactive PDF in jsp page